# Does diffraction limit on light divergence apply to all beams?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

The diffraction limit $\theta = {\lambda \over\pi w}$ is [generally referenced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_divergence) as a theoretical lower limit on light beam divergence.  However this limit seems to be based on the assumption that a tight light beam must be formed using an aperture and/or lens.

Is there anything intrinsic to a light beam traveling in a vacuum that makes it impossible for divergence to be zero?  If so, what is the source and nature of that fundamental lower limit on divergence?

Rephrasing the question: Is it theoretically possible that a light beam could be generated that has zero divergence?  If so, has such a thing been demonstrated in practice?

(I don't know how that would be done, although I have a mental image of something like a linear accelerator spitting particles in an arbitrarily tight beam, and some coupling mechanism that then directly stimulates the emission of photons in an equally tight beam.)

Comment: The source still has a finite size, defining an aperture.

Comment: @JonCuster – My understanding is that the sort of "aperture" that creates diffraction is a literal opaque barrier with a transparent opening (i.e., the "aperture") placed at a distance from the emission source.  If photons are emitted in a beam without having to traverse such a barrier then the question is whether diffraction (or any other divergence) of the beam must occur, and if so why.

Comment: Why do you think the source dimensions are not effectively an aperture? Works fine for, say, diode lasers.

Comment: @JonCuster – Because I am trying to draw inferences and make deductions based on a very limited knowledge and understanding of physics.  Corrections, clarifications, and explanations are most welcome.  E.g., if diode laser divergence is diffraction limited even absent anything functioning as a barrier aperture it would be helpful to know that, and to know why.

Comment: Well, yes it is, because the output face is in essence an aperture. If you play with a laser diode you will find that the divergence of the beam has two different angles - one is from the thickness of the active output area (thin) and one is from the width of the output area (wide). No matter what modes are active 'behind' the output face, it functions as a aperture.